# Excel VBA save cell data to separate sheet

Tags: vba, excel

How would I save my cell data from worksheet 1 to worksheet 2.

Basically I have a sheet like this :-

```
             |   Job number | Job notes

edit button  |   345345     |  just some text

edit button  |   345468     | more text

edit button  |   678934     | job info
```

On my excel sheet I have a command button on each row that when pressed opens a 
user form with a text box, this has a command button when the command button is pressed it searches for the job number and saves the text box data to the row with the correct job number I am editing.

code to save

```
Private Sub savejobnotes_Click()


Dim YourVariable As Variant
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim rownum As String
Set YourVariable = jobRef


With ActiveSheet.Range("D:D")
Set uRng = .Find(YourVariable, , xlValues, xlWhole, , MatchCase:=False, 
searchformat:=False)
If Not uRng Is Nothing Then
    uRng.Activate
    rowCount = ActiveCell.Row
    'this will find the row number  rowCount
   ' MsgBox rowCount

    rownum = "K" & rowCount
    MsgBox "Saved to " & rownum

    'save textbox value to a cell
    ActiveSheet.Range(rownum).Value = jobnotes.Value


 End If
End With
End Sub
```

Code to load the job notes into the text box when opening the user form.

```
Sub loadjobnotes()

Dim YourVariable As Variant
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim rownum As String
Set YourVariable = jobRef
With ActiveSheet.Range("D:D")
Set uRng = .Find(YourVariable, , xlValues, xlWhole, , MatchCase:=False, 
searchformat:=False)
If Not uRng Is Nothing Then
    uRng.Activate
    rowCount = ActiveCell.Row
    'this will find the row number  rowCount
   ' MsgBox rowCount

    rownum = "K" & rowCount
   ' MsgBox rownum

jobnotes.Value = ActiveSheet.Range(rownum)


  End If
 End With
End Sub
```

How would I save the job number and the job notes to a separate sheet each time. As I need to keep a copy of the job notes linked to the job number as my excel table gets updated from a .csv file regularly which removes any completed jobs from the table.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a new sheet named like **Jobs** and then use constructions like this:

```
Sheets("Jobs").Cells("coordinates here").Value = "your values"
```

Maybe you would be need to create a counter, but that's some other topic.

Comment: Thanks for the info i managed to build on that and now i am able to search for the job number and check if it exsists and if not add it to the new sheet or update it.